# Php Error not displaying on server

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

I am having a problem with a register fucntions, which works on XAMP but not my webserver. But the problem is that my webserver even doesnt display an error in the else part.

```html
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(ID, email, password, salt, credits, total_credits) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $uuid, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt, $credits, $total_credits);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();


// check for successful store
if ($result) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->close();

    return $user;
} else {
    die($stmt -> error); 
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't use mysqli much, but perhaps you don't want to call close() until you've read the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commeting out the close() methode worked.

Thank you to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have already closed the `$stmt` try instead using

```
die($this->conn -> error);
```